# get required runtime version from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, clr, appdomain

I need to get CLR version that my assembly requires and remove the assembly afterwards. Each of those separately is trivial, but if I want to do both of them I run into problems: to get the value of ImageRuntimeVersion property I need to load the assembly. This prevents me from deleting the file as it says the file is in use. I tried to load that file in a separate appdomain, but failed miserably (eg. got some errors that the file could not be found even if I loaded it using constructor that takes byte[] as argument or another error: SecurityException saying something about RegistryPermission).

Answer (score 1):

Could you just read the assembly into a memory stream and load that? It should save you from locking the the original assembly but I've seen from other comments this will cause any linked assemblies to lock.

Then the assembly you want to delete is just a disconnected file so after you've disposed of it after reading it in, you should be able to delete it.

Comment: +1. Note: this approach is fine if you never need to load same/similar assembly into the same app domain, otherwise there is a good chance that loading of next one will not pick correct binaries. If you need to load assembly with the same full name the only real option is to get it loaded in new AppDomain and destroy that new AppDomain as soon as you get necessary information.

Comment: This approach seems to work, but I need to check the scenario when the assembly changes (whether the new version will be picked up correctly). @AlexeiLevenkov - how do I actually load the assembly into new AppDomain?

Comment: @TomaszGrobelny the trick is to run loading code in the new AppDomain. Related questions cover that reasonably, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468151/appdomain-unload-doesnt-release-the-assembly-i-loaded-up-with-reflection?rq=1 seem to have proper sample.